# Error while converting the String to float.(NumberFormatException)

Tags: java, android, string, floating-point

Can you tell me how to achieve this in android:

Transform a `String` into a `float` as in:

`String temp="1,000,00"`

to

`float f=100f`

I had already gone through links. Getting this exception :

`java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: ""`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please go through our [ask] page first!

Comment: check if string is empty using if(!TextUtils.isEmpty("your string") do something

Comment: please show your code. The string is empty, there must an issue anywhere....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried like this:

```
String s = "100";
float f = Float.parseFloat(s);
```

and make sure that the String you are parsing is indeed a `float` and is not `null` or `empty`

Comment: yes it gives me value f=100.0..i want the value to be f=100f

Comment: Why would you want that?

Comment: Maybe OP want to format that string so it will look like float :D

Comment: @SagarGangawane `100f` is technically the same as `100.0`. `100f` is just a way of telling the compiler this is a `float` not and `int` for instance.

Comment: thanks for your reply but the method is not accepting the value It gives me exception as mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the Float class's parseFloat method.

It sounds like the problem is with the actual string you are using though - can you post that?

Comment: for (String y:years)
            {
                float f = Float.parseFloat(y);
                Log.e(TAG,"Value of float  \n"+ f + "Value of String  "+ y);
            }

Comment: post it as a part of your question please, not as a comment...

Comment: and what (using a debugger) is in "y" at this point?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Float](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html) class.

```
// String to Float 
float temp = Float.parseFloat("100f");

// Float to String: 
String str = Float.toString(100.0f);
```